# Why I'm not able to see reserve catalog under 'show catalogs' command on databricks notebook but able to see on databricks SQL editor?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Few days back we were able to see reserve catalog(spark_catalog) in databricks notebook. Not sure what happened, suddenly our process is failing due to not getting reserve catalog name under 'show catalogs' command in notebooks. And when I try to run 'show catalogs' on databricks SQL editor, It is giving the reserve catalog name in output. Please find below screenshots for more details.

SQL Editor output:
[image: SQL Editor output]

Databricks cell output:

[image: Databricks cell output]

Comment: do you have a cluster with unity catalog or table access control enabled?

Comment: @AlexOtt - No, unity catalog is not enabled for databricks cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I was using databricks 11.1 LTS runtime version. When I upgraded it to 12.2 LTS it is working as expected.